# Linear Algebra Question: How to prove $Q=\frac{1}{4m}s^TBs=\frac{1}{4m}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (u_i^T \cdot s)^2\beta_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Some background information:

$B$ is a symmetric matrix. The $u_i$'s represent $B$'s eigenvectors. The $\beta_i$'s represent B's eigenvalues. $s$ is a $nx1$ vector and $m$ is a constant.

Question: In lecture, my professor wrote that $Q=\frac{1}{4m}s^TBs=\frac{1}{4m}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (u_i^T \cdot s)^2\beta_i$

I am having some difficulty proving to myself that the statement is true.

Here is what I have done so far:

Because B is a symmteric matrix, I know that $s$ can be represented as a linear combination of the $u_i$'s. Thus, $s= \displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^n a_iu_i$.

Then, $Q=\frac{1}{4m}\displaystyle \sum_i a_iu_i^TB \displaystyle \sum_ja_ju_j$.

However, I am not sure where to go from here. Do I need to decompose B? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Write $B=U\Lambda U'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting where you left: you use that $B$ is linear, and that you chose the $u_i$ so that they form an orthonormal basis. Then

$$
Q=\frac{1}{4m} \sum_i a_iu_i^TB  \sum_ja_ju_j\\
=\frac{1}{4m}\displaystyle \sum_i \sum_ja_ja_iu_i^TB \displaystyle u_j\\
=\frac{1}{4m}\displaystyle \sum_i \sum_ja_ja_iu_i^T\beta_j u_j\\
=\frac{1}{4m}\displaystyle \sum_i \sum_j\beta_ja_ja_iu_i^T u_j\\
=\frac{1}{4m}\displaystyle \sum_i \beta_ia_i^2\\
=\frac{1}{4m}\displaystyle \sum_i \beta_i(u_i^T\cdot s)^2.
$$
Note that $u_i^T\cdot s=a_i$, and that $u_j^Tu_i=\delta_{i,j}$.

Comment: Maybe this is a trivial question, but could you explain to me how B can change to $\beta_i$ from lines 2-3?

Comment: The $u_i$ were chosen to be eigenvectors of $B$ corresponding to the $\beta_i$. This by definition means that $Bu_i=\beta_iu_i$.

Comment: Oh right! Of course. That makes sense. Thank you so much!